# Clean the '-x option' inside a script

Tags: linux, bash

I've been using "set -x" inside bash scripts in order to help me debug some functions, and it has been working very well for me

```
    -x      After  expanding  each  simple  command,  for command, case command,
            select command, or arithmetic  for  command,  display  the  expanded
            value  of PS4, followed by the command and its expanded arguments or
            associated word list.
```

However I'd like to be able to clear it before I leave the function

Eg:

```
    #/bin bash

    function somefunction() 
    {
        set -x

        # some code I'm debugging

        # clear the set -x
        set ????
    }

    somefunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a function like

```
foo () {
    set -x
    # do something
    set +x
}
```

The problem is that if the `-x` option was already set *before* `foo` was called, it will be turned off by `foo`.

If you want to restore the old value, you'll have to test whether it was enabled already using `$-`.

```
foo () {
    [[ $- != *x* ]]; x_set=$?    # 1 if already set, 0 otherwise
    set -x
    # do something
    (( x_set )) || set +x       # Turn off -x if it was off before
}
```

Comment: Being able to restore the previous state is a great improvement over what I was asking. Thanks!

Comment: I yearn for a world where something like `set ±x` would toggle the value. :)

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the manual:

> Using + rather than - causes these flags to be turned off.

So it's `set +x` what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For some more info always refer to the basic guide. This clearly gives you the answer :

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html

```
set -x          # activate debugging from here
w
set +x          # stop debugging from here
```